# Chromosome picture, how to interpret?

Tags: chromosome, drosophila

In this guide i was reading for annotations, there is a diagram of chromosomes of *D.mel*, I am confused as to why the chromosomes are all attached to one another, is this picture taken in a certain stage of mitosis in which they are all condensed?

[Original source](http://gep.wustl.edu/repository/course_materials_GEP_partners/Saville_McNeil_Annotation_Walkthrough.pdf)
 (page 2).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look up polytene (giant) chromosomes.

> Polytene chromosomes are over-sized chromosomes which have developed from standard chromosomes and are commonly found in the salivary glands of Drosophila melanogaster. Specialized cells undergo repeated rounds of DNA replication without cell division (endomitosis), to increase cell volume, forming a giant polytene chromosome. Polytene chromosomes form when multiple rounds of replication produce many sister chromatids that remain synapsed together.

You can read more about it at wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytene_chromosome)